# Why does eclipse tell me I should "accessed in a static way" for static method reference ClassName::staticMethod?

Tags: java, lambda, static-methods

I'm reading [Java 8 Method Reference: How to Use it](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx) and want to reuse TriFunction in other way:

```
    public class Numbers {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            TriFunction<Numbers, String, String, Integer> function = (s,  arg1,  arg2 ) -> Numbers.doSum(arg1, arg2);
            System.out.println(function.apply(new Numbers(), "1", "2"));

            //error, not warning: The method doSum(String, String) from the type Numbers should be accessed in a static way
            TriFunction<Numbers, String, String, Integer> mRef = Numbers::doSum;   
            System.out.println(mRef.apply(new Numbers(), "3", "4"));
        }

        static Integer doSum(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.parseInt(s1) + Integer.parseInt(s2);
        }
    } 

    interface TriFunction<T, U, V, R> {
        R apply(T t, U u, V v);
    }
```

I know that static method should be accessed in static way. But I don't think I break the rule with `Numbers::doSum`. So what is the reason?

Comment: The message seems misleading. Basically `doSum` shouldn't be `static` if you want that expression to work.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But there's no statement that method reference to static method is deprecated in Method References chapter in [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: This isn't about deprecation. That expression just doesn't make any sense. What do you think it should resolve to? How would you use the `mRef` and what would it call behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Numbers::doSum`, when applied to a `TriFunction<Numbers, String, String, Integer>`, translates to `(n, s1, s2) -> n.doSum(s1, s2)`, which means you're calling a static method on an instance of `Numbers`. Either make it an instance method, or use a `BiFunction` that doesn't expect a `Numbers` instance.

Comment: What is the problem of calling a static method on an instance? I think this should only get a warning instead of error, meanwhile the code runs correctly.

Comment: Indeed, it's just a warning.

Comment: Not in my case. I get an error, and the code doesn't run. This is information in eclipse console when I try to run the code: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method doSum(String, String) from the type Numbers should be accessed in a static way 

 at test.Numbers.main(Numbers.java:9)

Comment: Haven't actually tested, but I'll take your word for it. The fact that static members can be referenced from an instance is widely considered to be a design error. Maybe the designers decided there was no reason to support it for the new method reference syntax.

Comment: From [java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), ContainingClass::staticMethodName is exactly the way to create a method reference to a static method. And I tested that below code works:List<Character> list = Arrays.asList('a','b');
            list.stream().map(String::valueOf).forEach(System.out::println); where valueOf is static method. This really confuses me.

Comment: Correct, as long as you're calling the method statically. But here you're trying to call the static method on an instance. Otherwise, what happened to `T`?

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason now.

```
TriFunction<Numbers, String, String, Integer> mRef = Numbers::doSum;
```

here, `doSum()` should take 3 args, but actually it can only take 2 from the defination:

```
static Integer doSum(String s1, String s2) {}
```